# Ubuntu is lagging on a UN50JU6500F TV

Tags: display, hdmi

I have installed Ubuntu (24.04.4) and connected it through HDMI to the `UN50JU6500F Samsung TV`. When I log in, the mouse and really everything starts to lag *enormously*, rendering the PC unusable.

Funny but everything works fine on the login screen, no lag, nothing.

I have done `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` through the terminal and then `sudo reboot` but that did not help. The refresh rate was 30.00Hz the last time I checked (There were no options higher than that).

Terminal solutions are highly preferred for I literally cannot control the mouse.

Specs:

- TV: UN50JU6500F 50" Class JU6500 4K UHD Smart TV
- Video Card: https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/visiontek-radeon-hd-5450-2-gb-ddr3-pcie-21-x16-dvi-d-sub-hdmi-graphics-card-900356/apd/a6173020/graphic-video-cards
- PC: XPS 8700

Comment: Your PC is old-ish and the video card is not spectacular. I fear that is the cause of the issue, driving a large display at high resolution.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I guess that is the issue for it ran Ubuntu OK on a smaller display.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is weird because the error only came up on the _second_ day of usage.

Comment: Them it might be something else.

Comment: Consult the logs for clues.

Comment: @user535733 No Idea of what logs to consult.

Comment: Hook it up to a different screen. Then review /var/log/syslog. What you should look for: Error messages.

Comment: @user535733 Alright